# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target - Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a model called FilterOperation.ts that goes like this:

```
export class FilterOperations {
  constructor(
    public mainFilter : string,
    public currencyType : string,
    public status : string
    ) { }
}
```

Then have my component defined like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/operator/finally';

//models
import { Session }              from './src/models/session';
import { Client }              from './src/models/client';
import { Operation }              from './src/models/operation';
import { FilterOperations }              from './src/models/filterOperations';

//services
import { OperationSearchService }       from './src/services/operations_admin.service';

//constants
import * as constantsValues from "../../core/constants/constants";

@Component({
    templateUrl: './app/views/operations_admin/src/templates/operations_admin.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/views/operations_admin/css/operations_admin.css'],
    providers: [ OperationSearchService ]
})

export class OperationsAdminComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() filter: FilterOperations;
    errorMessage: string;
    clientFound: Client;
    sessionList: Session[];
    operationCount: number;
    mainSearchSelector: string;

    constructor (private operationSearchService: OperationSearchService) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.filter = new FilterOperations(); //HERE GOES THE ERROR
    }
    onChangeMainFilter(newValue) {
        this.mainSearchSelector = newValue;
    }
    findOperations() {
        //some code
    }
}
```

It keeps sending the same message when I try to compile it: "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target ". What am I doing wrong when initializing the value of filter:

```
this.filter = new FilterOperations();
```

Answer (score 9):

Your code for `FilterOperations`:

```
export class FilterOperations {
    constructor(
        public mainFilter : string,
        public currencyType : string,
        public status : string
    ) { }
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
export class FilterOperations {
    public mainFilter: string;
    public currencyType: string;
    public status: string;

    constructor(mainFilter: string, currencyType: string, status: string) {
        this.mainFilter = mainFilter;
        this.currencyType = currencyType;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Though you probably meant to do:

```
export class FilterOperations {
    public mainFilter: string;
    public currencyType: string;
    public status: string;

    constructor() {}
}
```

In the first two the constructor expects 3 arguments, but when you instantiate it you're not passing any:

```
this.filter = new FilterOperations();
```

If you want an empty ctor then use my 3rd code snippet.
You can also do:

```
export class FilterOperations {
    constructor(
        public mainFilter?: string,
        public currencyType?: string,
        public status?: string
    ) { }
}
```

Now that all argument are optional you can call the ctor with no args.

Comment: `public` key words is matter